# Coded UI failing on the exception "Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible ...." on a dialog window

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, vstest

I can't seem to get past this exception on my coded UI project for a window dialog box. I've tried using always search and some other options. I was trying to use the option of open a window dialog button but that didn't seem to work since i did not see the open button only "OK" and a few ones that didn't pertain to what i was trying to do.

I see one of my window is returning 5 windows, I'm trying to use the code Order Of overcation but that doesn't seem to work.

Currently here is my latest code which is still not working and still giving me the same exception error

```
   WinWindow myDialogBox = new WinWindow();
        myDialogBox.FilterProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.OrderOfInvocation, "5");
        myDialogBox.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        myDialogBox.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "DirectUIHWND";
        myDialogBox.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "0";

        myDialogBox.DrawHighlight();


        WinWindow MyOpbenButton = new WinWindow(myDialogBox);
     //   myDialogBox.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.OrderOfInvocation, "0");
        MyOpbenButton.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        MyOpbenButton.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "&Open";
        MyOpbenButton.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Button";
        //MyOpbenButton.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "0";
        MyOpbenButton.DrawHighlight();


        //Testing this window produces 5 window with the same name and 
        control ID.  

        WinWindow matchingWindows = new WinWindow(myDialogBox);

       matchingWindows.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "&Open");

      //  matchingWindows.SearchProperties.Add("ControlId", "0");
       matchingWindows.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "Button");



        UITestControlCollection windowsFound = matchingWindows.FindMatchingControls();




        WinPane MyOpbenPane = new WinPane(MyOpbenButton);
        MyOpbenPane.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        //MyOpbenPane.SearchProperties[WinPane.PropertyNames.Name] = "Open";
        MyOpbenPane.SearchProperties[WinPane.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Button";
        // var myDialog = sharedControls.UIWindowsInternetExploWindow.UIWindowsInternetExplo_Open_Save_Dialog_LinksPage.UIItemWindow;           
        MyOpbenPane.DrawHighlight();
        return MyOpbenPane;
```

The error message that this is producing is the following:

> Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked
>   control visible and retry the action. Additional Details:
>   \r\nTechnologyName:  'MSAA'\r\nName:  '&Open'\r\nClassName: 
>   'Button'\r\nControlType:  'Window'\r\n

Comment: What event triggered error?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question. What is "Order Of overcation"? Within "which is still now working" should "now" be replaced by "not"?

Comment: hi @utility, the event that is triggering error is after i return the winpane MyOpbenPane which is where the open button is located on the window dialogue i try to do a mouse click on it. When i try to do this mouse click even thats when i get the exception please make the blocked control visible and retry the action....

Comment: hi @AdrianHHH i have made the fix to the question

Comment: It still says "Order Of overcation".

Answer (score 0):

I used the test builder to get around this issue.

I found that the dialog screen was being captured with the 
classname of 32770.  I also found that i could not pass off my browser window to window from there i hand coded the remaining screen using the test builder.

here is the code below.

```
  WinWindow window = new WinWindow();
        window.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        window.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);
        window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "#32770";
        window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Windows Internet Explorer";
        window.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Internet Explorer");

        //window.DrawHighlight();

        WinCustom myDialogBox = new WinCustom(window);
        myDialogBox.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);
        myDialogBox.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        myDialogBox.SearchProperties[WinCustom.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Dialog";
        myDialogBox.SearchProperties[WinCustom.PropertyNames.Name] = "Windows Internet Explorer";
        myDialogBox.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Internet Explorer");
        //myDialogBox.DrawHighlight();

        WinWindow myDialogwindow = new WinWindow(window);
        myDialogwindow.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);
        myDialogwindow.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        myDialogwindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.AccessibleName] = "Windows Internet Explorer";
        myDialogwindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "DirectUIHWND";
        myDialogwindow.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Internet Explorer");

        return myDialogwindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this a lot. I have an application on which the tabs always get reported as hidden, even though they're clearly visible. What has worked well for me so far has been to use keyboard.sendkeys to send keystrokes that select the tab.